# How to put variable inside angular.element?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to make my own tag maanger. I use bootstrap typeahead and add directive to this element and listen broadcast on select action. I struggleed with adding btn with variable inside it and I haven't find yet the way to put it into the input field (and support stretching for that)

How I can put my `$scope.item` into `angular.element("<div>{{$scope.item}}</div>")` ?

```
mainApp.directive("tagsManager", ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log("Tags in directive: " + scope.tags);
            scope.$on('tags.new', function(event, tag) {
                console.log("New tag is arrived: " + tag.name);
                var el = angular.element("<div class=\"btn btn-default\">tag.name</div>");
//                $scope.items = teamSharedObj.teams;
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.after(el);
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Have you tried `angular.element("<div>{{item}}</div>")`?

Comment: Yes, just put {{item}} as a string not, a var

Comment: Made a hack by using replace but I suppose there is should be a better solution

Comment: pretty simple by using concatenation ..`'<div>' + tag.name + '</div>'`

Comment: It is the same as using replace but I think it is not a proper way in js and angular as well, isn't it? I am novice in the font-end dev

Comment: Use `ng-bind` or `data-ng-bind` instead. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/k4xmodf3/

Comment: Thank you, it works! If you make your comment as a post I can acept it as an answer.